# React Native Native Base Tabs Not Showing Content. Blank Screen and tabs not working

Tags: react-native, native-base

I am working a small RN Learning project and is using Native Base Library. I am facing difficulty while using the tabs from native-base.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Container, Tab, Tabs, TabHeading, Icon, Text} from 'native-base';
import Tab1 from './tabs/TabOne';
import Tab2 from './tabs/TabTwo';
export default class TabScreen extends Component {
 render() {
   return (
     <Container>
      <Tabs>
      <Tab
        heading={
          <TabHeading>
            <Icon name="camera" />
            <Text>Camera</Text>
          </TabHeading>
        }>
        <Tab1 />
      </Tab>
      <Tab
        heading={
          <TabHeading>
            <Text>No Icon</Text>
          </TabHeading>
        }>
        <Tab2 />
      </Tab>
    </Tabs>
  </Container>
);
}
}
```

Tab 1 and tab 2 are just text components.

Below are the version of library I am using

"native-base": "^2.13.12",
    "react": "16.11.0",
    "react-native": "^0.62.2",

Below is the output

[image]

Tabs are not clickable and no text is rendered. I checked the color of text as well and it's not white Kindly let me know what's the mistake in the code

Below is my tabOne Code

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';

const TabOne = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>
        This is a long long text. This is a long long text. This is a long long
    text. This is a long long text.
      </Text>
    </View>
   );
};

export default TabOne;
```

Comment: what do You see in js console and react dev-tools?

Comment: I tried your code and it's working for me, may be the problem is in TabOne or TabTwo.

Comment: I have added tabone code, tab2 is also same just the difference in name. Can you please suggest if I am doing something wrong in that. @MahdiN